# Is it possible to make CPython aware of type hints?

Tags: python, type-hinting, cpython

As mentioned in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals):

> Using type hints for performance optimizations is left as an exercise for the reader.

Assuming one would be interested in doing this exercise, how hard would it be to undertake, even partially? Is there prior art for using type-hinting in an interpreted language to improve execution speed or is this only possible by going with a JIT compiler?

I should note that I also understand that this is a non-goal and that:

> Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.

Consequently, I understand that efforts moving to improve speed would go against this by encouraging type hints by convention. However, I'm still curious about the difficulty of this task.

**Update:** Although this question is too broad for this site, it is [partially answered in the PyPy FAQ](https://pypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#would-type-annotations-help-pypy-s-performance):

> ... the speed benefits would be extremely minor.
>
> There are several reasons for why.
>
> One of them is that annotations are
>   at the wrong level (e.g. a PEP 484 “int” corresponds to Python 3’s int
>   type, which does not necessarily fits inside one machine word; even
>   worse, an “int” annotation allows arbitrary int subclasses).
>
> Another
>   is that a lot more information is needed to produce good code (e.g.
>   “this `f()` called here really means this function there, and will never
>   be monkey-patched” – same with `len()` or `list()`, btw). The third
>   reason is that some “guards” in PyPy’s JIT traces don’t really have an
>   obvious corresponding type (e.g. “this dict is so far using keys which
>   don’t override `__hash__` so a more efficient implementation was
>   used”). Many guards don’t even have any correspondence with types at
>   all (“this class attribute was not modified”; “the loop counter did
>   not reach zero so we don’t need to release the GIL”; and so on).

Comment: I'm super uncertain if this is a good question or if this is the right site for this question. I looked at posting this on cs.stackexchange.com and softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, but I wasn't sure if this was the right type of theory for these sites. I think this question is subjective, but answerable. A good answer would go over the challenges of this implementation with links to resources for further reading.

Comment: They are hints, not promises. Without some extra requirement (eg using mypy) you can't really use the hints for anything performance wise. I guess an implementation like pypy could compile beforehand. But it's really outside cpython's scope

Comment: @JohnLaRooy If you added some information about the difference between hints and promises, I would totally accept that as an answer.

Comment: Well, I think hints don't enforce the type. This means the function can still accept (and work with) other input types as specified by the hint.

Comment: *I'm super uncertain if this is a good question or if this is the right site for this question*: indeed, this is not a good site for this question. It's really too broad as posted.

Comment: The PyPy FAQ addresses some of your questions, however: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#would-type-annotations-help-pypy-s-performance